# Fill area in cube

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

I need to fill cube with colors but i get only half of the figure filled. I believe there is a problem with cubeIndices but cant get how to make it fill everything.I know i can use cylinder but i'm learning algorithms so i'd like to do it using lines.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Cube</title>
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
      color: rgb(43, 10, 74);
      height: 99vh;
      border: 3px solid black;
      border-radius: 1em;
      margin: 0 100px;
      padding: 0 20px;
    }
    
    button {
      font-size: 1.05em;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin: 1em;
      transition: .5s;
      border: 3px solid;
      border-radius: .5em;
      width: 200px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    button:hover {
      background-color: rgb(12, 12, 12);
      color: aliceblue;
    }
    
    input {
      height: 40px;
      width: 50px;
      border-radius: .3em;
      border: 0;
      background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
      font-size: 2em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    input:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="number" id="segmentInput" min="3" max="50" value="6">
  <button id="updateButton">Оновити</button>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/three.texttexture@0.9.2/dist/three.texttexture.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    let scene, camera, renderer, axesHelper, cube, circle, circle2;
    let segments = 6;
    let rotationSpeed = 0.005;

    function init() {

      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, 500 / 500, 1, 500);
      camera.position.set(7, 5, 10);
      camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(500, 500);
      renderer.getContext().getShaderInfoLog = function() {
        return '';
      };
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
      renderer.setClearColor("white");;
      createCube();
      createCircles();
    }




    function createCube() {
      const radiusBottom = 2;
      const radiusTop = 2;
      const height = 2;
      const cubeVertices = new Float32Array((segments + 1) * 6);
      for (let i = 0; i <= segments; i++) {
        const angle = (i / segments) * Math.PI * 2;
        const x = Math.cos(angle);
        const z = Math.sin(angle);

        const topX = x * radiusTop;
        const topZ = z * radiusTop;
        const topY = height / 2;

        const bottomX = x * radiusBottom;
        const bottomZ = z * radiusBottom;
        const bottomY = -height / 2;

        const baseOffset = i * 6;
        cubeVertices[baseOffset] = topX;
        cubeVertices[baseOffset + 1] = topY;
        cubeVertices[baseOffset + 2] = topZ;

        cubeVertices[baseOffset + 3] = bottomX;
        cubeVertices[baseOffset + 4] = bottomY;
        cubeVertices[baseOffset + 5] = bottomZ;
      }
      const cubeIndices = new Uint16Array(segments * 12);

      for (let i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
        const faceOffset = i * 12;

        cubeIndices[faceOffset] = i * 2;
        cubeIndices[faceOffset + 1] = (i + 1) * 2;
        cubeIndices[faceOffset + 2] = i * 2 + 1;

        cubeIndices[faceOffset + 3] = i * 2;
        cubeIndices[faceOffset + 4] = (i + 1) * 2;
        cubeIndices[faceOffset + 5] = i * 2;

        cubeIndices[faceOffset + 6] = i * 2;
        cubeIndices[faceOffset + 7] = i * 2 + 1;
        cubeIndices[faceOffset + 8] = (i + 1) * 2;

        cubeIndices[faceOffset + 9] = (i + 1) * 2;
        cubeIndices[faceOffset + 10] = i * 2 + 1;
        cubeIndices[faceOffset + 11] = (i + 1) * 2;

      }

      cubeGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
      cubeGeometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(cubeIndices, 1));
      cubeGeometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(cubeVertices, 3));


      const cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 'blue'
      });
      cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
      scene.add(cube);
    }

    function createCircles() {
      const radiusBottom = 2;
      const radiusTop = 2;
      const circleShape = new THREE.Shape();
      circleShape.absarc(-1, 1, radiusTop, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      const circleShape1 = new THREE.Shape();
      circleShape1.absarc(-1, 1, radiusBottom, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      const circleGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(new THREE.ShapeGeometry(circleShape));
      const circleGeometry1 = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(new THREE.ShapeGeometry(circleShape1));
      const circleMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 'rgb(155, 58, 50)'
      });
      circle = new THREE.Line(circleGeometry, circleMaterial);
      circle2 = new THREE.Line(circleGeometry1, circleMaterial);
      circle.position.set(1, 1, 1);
      circle2.position.set(1, -1, 1);
      circle.rotation.x = Math.PI * 1.5;
      circle2.rotation.x = Math.PI * 1.5;
      scene.add(circle);
      scene.add(circle2);
    }

    function resetScene() {
      scene.remove(cube);
      scene.remove(circle);
      scene.remove(circle2);

      renderer.domElement.remove();
      init();
      animate();
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    const updateButton = document.getElementById('updateButton');
    updateButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      updateSegments();
    });
    document.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
      updateSegments();
    });

    function updateSegments() {
      const inputElement = document.getElementById('segmentInput');
      const newSegments = parseInt(inputElement.value);

      if (!isNaN(newSegments)) {
        segments = Math.max(3, Math.min(50, newSegments));
        resetScene();
      }
    }

    function animate() {
      cube.rotation.y += rotationSpeed;

      const radius = 10;
      const angle = Date.now() * 0.0005;

      const cameraX = Math.cos(angle) * radius;
      const cameraZ = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
      const cameraY = Math.sin(angle) * radius;

      camera.position.set(cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ);
      camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

      renderer.render(scene, camera);

      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    init();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Cant get whats wrong,i'm a little bit new to this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically nothing special. Something wasn't working as it supposed to and i made some fixex,added fill ,spinning just for fun.
Here's the code:

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">

                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <title>Cube</title>
                    <style>
                        body {
                            display: flex;
                            align-items: center;
                            justify-content: center;
                            flex-direction: column-reverse;
                            color: rgb(43, 10, 74);
                            height: 99vh;
                            border: 3px solid black;
                            border-radius: 1em;
                            margin: 0 100px;
                            padding: 0 20px;
                        }

                        button {
                            font-size: 1.05em;
                            font-weight: 600;
                            margin: 1em;
                            transition: .5s;
                            border: 3px solid;
                            border-radius: .5em;
                            width: 200px;
                            height: 40px;
                            background-color: white;
                        }

                        button:hover {
                            background-color: rgb(12, 12, 12);
                            color: aliceblue;
                        }

                        input {
                            height: 40px;
                            width: 50px;
                            border-radius: .3em;
                            border: 0;
                            background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
                            font-size: 2em;
                            text-align: center;
                        }

                        input:focus {
                            outline: none;
                        }

                        canvas {
                            z-index: 999;
                        }
                    </style>
                </head>

                <body>
                    <input type="number" id="segmentInput" min="3" max="50" value="6">
                    <button id="updateButton">Оновити</button>

                    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three.texttexture@0.9.2/dist/three.texttexture.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>

                    <script>
                        let scene, camera, renderer, axesHelper, cube, circle, circle2, mask;
                        let segments = 6;
                        let rotationSpeed = 0.005;

                        function init() {
                            scene = new THREE.Scene();
                            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, 1, 1, 1000);
                            camera.position.set(10, 10, 10);
                            camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
                            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                            renderer.setSize(500, 500);
                            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
                            renderer.setClearColor("white");
                            createCube();
                            createCircles();
                        }

                        function createCube() {
                            const radius = 2;
                            const height = 2;
                            const cubeVertices = new Float32Array((segments + 1) * 6);

                            for (let i = 0; i <= segments; i++) {
                                const angle = (i / segments) * Math.PI * 2;
                                const x = Math.cos(angle);
                                const z = Math.sin(angle);

                                const topX = x * radius;
                                const topZ = z * radius;
                                const topY = height / 2;

                                const bottomX = x * radius;
                                const bottomZ = z * radius;
                                const bottomY = -height / 2;

                                const baseOffset = i * 6;
                                cubeVertices[baseOffset] = topX;
                                cubeVertices[baseOffset + 1] = topY;
                                cubeVertices[baseOffset + 2] = topZ;

                                cubeVertices[baseOffset + 3] = bottomX;
                                cubeVertices[baseOffset + 4] = bottomY;
                                cubeVertices[baseOffset + 5] = bottomZ;
                            }

                            const cubeIndices = new Uint16Array(segments * 12);

                            for (let i = 0; i <= segments; i++) {
                                const faceOffset = i * 12;

                                cubeIndices[faceOffset] = i * 2;
                                cubeIndices[faceOffset + 1] = (i + 1) * 2;
                                cubeIndices[faceOffset + 2] = i * 2 + 1;

                                cubeIndices[faceOffset + 3] = i * 2;
                                cubeIndices[faceOffset + 4] = (i + 1) * 2;
                                cubeIndices[faceOffset + 5] = i * 2 + 1;

                                cubeIndices[faceOffset + 6] = i * 2 + 1;
                                cubeIndices[faceOffset + 7] = (i + 1) * 2;
                                cubeIndices[faceOffset + 8] = (i + 1) * 2 + 1;

                                cubeIndices[faceOffset + 9] = i * 2 + 1;
                                cubeIndices[faceOffset + 10] = (i + 1) * 2 + 1;
                                cubeIndices[faceOffset + 11] = (i + 1) * 2 + 1;
                            }

                            cubeGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
                            cubeGeometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(cubeIndices, 1));
                            cubeGeometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(cubeVertices, 3));

                            const cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                                color: 'blue',
                                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                                renderOrder: 0,
                            });

                            cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);

                            const topBottomMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                                color: 'blue',
                                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                            });

                            const topBottomGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(radius, segments);
                            const topBottomMesh = new THREE.Mesh(topBottomGeometry, topBottomMaterial);
                            topBottomMesh.position.set(0, height / 2, 0);
                            topBottomMesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
                            cube.add(topBottomMesh);

                            const bottomGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(radius, segments);
                            const bottomMesh = new THREE.Mesh(bottomGeometry, topBottomMaterial);
                            bottomMesh.position.set(0, -height / 2, 0);
                            bottomMesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
                            cube.add(bottomMesh);

                            const edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(cubeGeometry);
                            const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000 });
                            const lines = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, lineMaterial);

                            cube.add(lines);
                            scene.add(cube);
                        }



                        function createCircles() {
                            const radiusBottom = 2;
                            const radiusTop = 2;
                            const circleShape = new THREE.Shape();
                            circleShape.absarc(-1, 1, radiusTop, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                            const circleShape1 = new THREE.Shape();
                            circleShape1.absarc(-1, 1, radiusBottom, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                            const circleGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(new THREE.ShapeGeometry(circleShape));
                            const circleGeometry1 = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(new THREE.ShapeGeometry(circleShape1));
                            const circleMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 'rgb(155, 58, 50)' });
                            circle = new THREE.Line(circleGeometry, circleMaterial);
                            circle2 = new THREE.Line(circleGeometry1, circleMaterial);
                            circle.position.set(1, 1, 1);
                            circle2.position.set(1, -1, 1);
                            circle.rotation.x = Math.PI * 1.5;
                            circle2.rotation.x = Math.PI * 1.5;
                            scene.add(circle);
                            scene.add(circle2);
                        }

                        function resetScene() {
                            scene.remove(cube);
                            scene.remove(circle);
                            scene.remove(circle2);
                            scene.remove(mask); // Видаляємо маску

                            renderer.domElement.remove();
                            init();
                            animate();
                            renderer.render(scene, camera);
                        }

                        const updateButton = document.getElementById('updateButton');
                        updateButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
                            updateSegments();
                        });

                        document.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
                            updateSegments();
                        });

                        function updateSegments() {
                            const inputElement = document.getElementById('segmentInput');
                            const newSegments = parseInt(inputElement.value);

                            if (!isNaN(newSegments)) {
                                segments = Math.max(3, Math.min(50, newSegments));
                                resetScene();
                            }
                        }

                        function animate() {
                            cube.rotation.y += rotationSpeed;

                            const radius = 10;
                            const angle = Date.now() * 0.0005;

                            const cameraX = Math.cos(angle) * radius;
                            const cameraZ = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
                            const cameraY = Math.sin(angle) * radius;

                            camera.position.set(cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ);
                            camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

                            renderer.render(scene, camera);
                            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                        }

                        init();
                    </script>
                </body>

                </html>
```